# most pythonic3 dezip(?) implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, code-readability

("dezip" is obviously a bad name, but I'm not sure what the right one would be. Please excuse me if that means I've missed an authoritative answer by not knowing what to search for.)

Let's say we have

```
people = [
    (1, 'anne'),
    (2, 'ben'),
    (3, 'charlie'),
]
```

(common in django for choices etc.)

Now we want a list of "keys" or list of the first elements: `[1, 2, 3]`

In python 3 I'm using

```
people_ids, _ = list(zip(*people))
# or even
people_ids = [p[0] for p in people]
```

The zip way doesn't seem very neat, particularly with the extra `list(...)` required by python 3 making zip an iterator.

The second comprehension approach is slightly more readable but wouldn't generalise as well, eg. return lists of the the second, third elements etc. in the same call.

Is there a better way?

(where "better" mainly means clean and readable but performance might also have some considerable)

Comment: _The second comprehension approach is slightly more readable but wouldn't generalise as well, eg. return lists of the the second, third elements etc._ why it won't? Pass it a single number, it'll return single element. Pass it a slice object, it'll return slice of original sliced list. It looks like nice and neat solution.

Comment: Let says we want `people_ids, people_names = [???]` can't be done in one readable comprehension AFAIK. But maybe you're right, if you just want one set of elements, be clear and write out the comprehension.

Comment: updated to clarify what I mean by "second, third elements"

Answer (score 2):

Using [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), you can get the first item from the iterable:

```
>>> people = [
...     (1, 'anne'),
...     (2, 'ben'),
...     (3, 'charlie'),
... ]
>>> next(zip(*people))
(1, 2, 3)
```

alternative using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) with [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> import operator
>>> list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), people))
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

BTW, `zip` solution without `list` should work:

```
>>> people_ids, _ = zip(*people)
>>> people_ids
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: sorry, what you can't do is `people_ids = zip(*people)[0]`. You have a typo, I guess you mean with**out**

Comment: I guess the real answer to my question is **NO**. But this is probably closest to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular example, you can "abuse" a little bit the `dict`:

```
people = [
    (1, 'anne'),
    (2, 'ben'),
    (3, 'charlie'),
]

d_people = dict(people)
```

And then you have a nice data model. This has some problems: keys cannot be repeated, and won't work with tuples with more than two elements. But for this case (which is quite typical!) works very nicely.

Then you can simply get the keys by doing `keys`:

```
d_people.keys()
```

or, explicit list, either:

```
list(d_people)
list(d_people.keys())
```

which are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a subset based on ids may be done by `operator.itemgetter`. Getting a subslice of zipped values may be done by creating explicit slice object and pass it to function.

```
import operator

people = [
    (1, 'anne', 'some'),
    (2, 'ben', 'another'),
    (3, 'charlie', 'field'),
]

people_ids = [p[0] for p in people]  # 0 may be passed as funtion argument
people_ids_and_another = [operator.itemgetter(*[0, 2])(p) for p in people]  # [0, 2] may be passed as function argument
people_ids_and_name_via_slice = [p[slice(0,2,None)] for p in people]  # equal to p[0:2], but passable as argument
```

To demonstrate function usage:

```
def dezip(seq, what):
    if isinstance(what, list):
        return [operator.itemgetter(*what)(p) for p in people]
    else:
        return [p[what] for p in people]

assert dezip(people, slice(0,2,None)) == [(1, 'anne'), (2, 'ben'), (3, 'charlie')]
assert dezip(people, 0) == [1, 2, 3]
assert dezip(people, [0, 2]) == [(1, 'some'), (2, 'another'), (3, 'field')]
```

If you'll drop 'list of indices' requirement, you may drop if statement in function body.